# Filtrar y ordenar por mayor cantidad de habitantes

Tags: python, django

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy trabajando con `Django` y necesito obtener un listado con las ciudades ordenadas por la que mas habitantes posea, aquí dejo los modelos que estoy usando.

```
class Ciudad(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=4,)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Persona(models.Model):
    ciudad_residencia = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, null=True, blank=True,
                        verbose_name=_("ciudad de residencia*"), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

La idea es poder obtener el nombre de las 5 ciudades con mayor numero de personas y mostrar el nombre de la ciudad y junto a eso el numero de personas en una tabla en `reporlab`, por eso lo almaceno en una lista.

Estoy usando un ciclo `for` pero me gustaría saber si existe una forma mas optima de hacerlo, continuación el código del recorrido.

```
ciudades = Ciudad.objects.all()
personas = Personas.objects.all()
contador_registros = 0
for ciudad in ciudades:
    personas_ciudad = personas.filter(ciudad_residencia=ciudad)
    if personas_ciudad.count() > 0:
        tabla_personas_ciudad.append(
            [ciudad.nombre,
             personas_ciudad.count()
             ]
        )
        contador_registros = contador_registros + 1
    if contador_registros >= 5:
        break
```

Ademas no se como ordenarlo de mayor a menor numero de personas en la ciudad.

Comment: @JackNavaRow excelente solo faltaria agregar que retorne los 5 con limit "[:5]"..

Comment: @JackNavaRow eso debió ser una buena respuesta.

Comment: @JackNavaRow la pregunta está muy clara. Creo que no hay nada que esperar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suponiendo que quieres hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT ciudad.nombre, count(personas.id_ciudad) as num_habitantes 
  FROM ciudad 
 INNER JOIN personas 
    ON personas.id_ciudad = ciudad.id 
 GROUP BY (ciudad.nombre) 
 ORDER BY count(personas.id_ciudad);
```

Django tiene [funciones de Agregacion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/), en este caso necesitamos el Count, tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
from django.db.models import Count
ciudades_con_total_habitantes = Ciudad.objects.annotate(num_habitantes=Count('personas')).order_by('-num_habitantes')
```

Ahora bien quieres ver el top 5 de ciudades con mayor habitantes, previamente lo ordenamos de mayor a menor, solo queda cortar el resultado

```
ciudades_con_total_habitantes[:5]
```

Comment: Excelente información, muchas gracias he solucionado mi problema.